# Catch 403 error when retrieving module through import()

Tags: javascript

This is a pretty straightforward issue, so I'm surprised I can't find it here.

Let's say I have the following code to import a module:

```
import("mymodule.js").then(module => {
    // Use module
}).catch(e => {
    // Handle error
});
```

So I expect that this will fail when the resource can't be retrieved or such, and this will be handled. But, if the request gets a 403, I get a "GET mysource.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403" error on the console. Once the request is cached the error no longer appears on each import().

It was my intention to use import() to check whether the module exists and retrieve it, so my question now is whether:

1. Using import() on resources that may not exist/are inaccessible is bad practice
2. Would I have to try to get the resource directly before running import to avoid the seemingly unhandled 403 error.

Comment: Are you using some kind of bundler that's handling dynamic import for you? If so, which one? If not, what browser(s) are you seeing this behavior in?

Comment: I'm not using any bundler, you can write this code in Chrome console to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So the answer is: "I'm seeing this in Chrome."

Comment: Yes, I assumed that answered both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [draft spec text](https://tc39.es/proposal-dynamic-import/#sec-hostimportmoduledynamically), if the `import` fails, the promise must be rejected. If you're not seeing that, then whatever is handling that dynamic `import` for you is not following the proposed spec text.

That said, I can't replicate this in Chrome v78. I set up an Express.js server and serve a 403 reply for the module. I correctly get a rejection. Here's the code I'm using on the client:

```
function tryIt(label) {
    import("./alskdfmod.js")
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`${label}: Worked`);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(`${label}: Failed: ${e.message}`);
    });
}
tryIt(1);
setTimeout(() => {
    tryIt(2);
}, 1000);
```

I get both rejections, 1 and 2.

> my question now is whether:
>
> 1. Using import() on resources that may not exist/are inaccessible is bad practice

In some sense, that's what it's *for*.

> 2. Would I have to try to get the resource directly before running import to avoid the seemingly unhandled 403 error.

You shouldn't need to. I would look more closely at your code, you should be getting a rejection on 403 (and 404 and any other failure to get the module).

---

In a comment you've said:

> I am getting the rejection, but I'm still getting the error in the console.

Ah! I misunderstood the question. Yes, network errors always show up as errors in the console in Chrome. (If you navigate to a site without a favicon, you'll see a 404 for favicon.ico as well.) You can safely ignore it. If you weren't handling the error, you'd be seeing a *second* error for the unhandled rejection.

Comment: I am getting the rejection, but I'm still getting the error in the console.

Comment: @blobber2 - Ah! I understand now. Updated the answer.